# cin statement will not compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cin

Alright, I have a programming challenge due but unfortunately, although my code does in theory, doesn't work so I was wondering if it was a compiler issue (I use Code::Blocks) or if its something I'm not seeing. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   double sliceStore, sliceSize = 14.125, totalSlice, area;

cout << "How Many Slices?" << endl;
//getline(cin,sliceStore);
cin >> sliceStore >> endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: `endl` is a constant. You should not try to change its value. Use it only with output statements, not input.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `cin >> endl`?  You may want to look at `std::istream::ignore`, specifically, `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I do not think he needs ignore, he just blindly copied `endl` from output without understanding what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "endl" from the input statement !!

Answer (score 0):

The complete error message for this is not nice and goes on for a few pages, but code::blocks usually fronts GCC and g++, GCC's C++ compiler, should have started the message of with something like this:

```
 cin >> sliceStore >> endl;
                   ^
```

In English, the compiler could not find a way for the >> operator to put data into `endl`. A bit of reading up on what [endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is may have solved your problem. `endl` is a function, not a variable.

```
ostream& endl(ostream&)
```

Crack your textbook and read up on input and output streams.

`cin` is the name of an input stream attached to the main console, usually represented by the command prompt. Input streams use >>,  which is also a function, one that usually looks like

```
istream& operator>>(istream&, somedatatype&)
```

So cin >> endl; really looks like is a function call something like

```
cin = operator>>(cin, endl());
```

However, no one has built an operator>> with a somedatatype that looks like `ostream& endl(ostream&)` and the compiler prints out a huge list of operator>> possibilities that look something like it as a hint of what you might have meant to do.

Most of the time this is helpful. Most functions only have a couple overloads, and you can quickly see what you did wrong. But operator>> has an overload for every common datatype and dozens of not so common data types. Blah.

Onto what the `endl` function does.

It tells an output stream to do two things: to end the line and to flush the output buffer.

Ending the line's pretty simple, the only caveat is everybody seems to do it differently so if you compile the same program under different operating systems you'll get slightly different output.

The output buffer flush is a instruction to the output stream to send any data it's been holding onto, buffering, for a good chance to send it.You generally want to send stuff in chunks because it's more efficient. Say you want to write to a file. In the world of a computer where things happen in nanoseconds, writing to a file can take seconds. For example, the hard disk could be in a low power sleep state and have to start spinning. Then it has to find where the file goes on the hard drive. Then it has to wait for the hard drive to spin into the right position. You don't want to go through all that just to write one character as each time you press a key on the keyboard, so the computer builds up a bunch of writes in memory--the buffer--thee writes the contents of the buffer after it fills up, hasn't been added to for a while, or is forced to with a flush instruction. `endl` provides that flush. As a result, overuse of `endl` can slow down your program.